# Operator defined on orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Question**: Let $H$ be Hilbert, $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ an orthonormal basis for $H$. Define $T(\phi_n) = \dfrac{\phi_{n}}{n}$.

How can I get a general formula for $Tx,\  x \in H$?

**Solution**: The obvious answer is $Tx = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \langle \phi_n , x \rangle  \dfrac{\phi_n}{n}$, but I can't justify this.

\begin{align*}Tx &= T \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle \phi_n, x \rangle \phi_n \right) \\
&= T \left(  \lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \langle \phi_n, x \rangle \phi_n \right) \\
&\stackrel{*}{=} \lim \limits_{k \to \infty} T \left( \sum_{n=1}^k \langle \phi_n, x \rangle \phi_n \right) \\
&= \lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \langle \phi_n, x \rangle T \phi_n \\
&=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle \phi_n , x \rangle  \dfrac{\phi_n}{n}
\end{align*}
and step $*$ follows from boundedness of $T$ . . . but I can't show $T$ is a bounded operator since defining $Tx$ relies on boundedness.  . .

Likely just a conceptual error on my part; please let me know if you have any input.

Comment: The misunderstanding is indeed conceptual. The statement "$T \phi_n = \frac{\phi_n}{n}$" is undefined because there may be lots of (unbounded) linear maps on $H$ satisfying this property, since the $\phi_n$ do not form a Hamel basis for $H$. Instead, for $x \in H$, we should just **define** $Tx := \sum_j \langle x, \phi_j \rangle \frac{\phi_j}{j}$. Now, using this definition, it is easily shown that $T$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks @Shalop. It was a problem I saw on someone's course notes online . . . I should have recognized it was undefined since $(\phi_n)$ is only a Shauder basis.

Comment: @Shalop: Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Shalop : Your answer is a good one, and would be nice to preserve as an answer, as Eric suggested.